# Clickhouse 'lightweight deletes' are not filtered from subsequent queries as expected, only filtered once asynchronous call is complete

Tags: sql-delete, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I am trying out the new clickhouse lightweight deletes, which deletes rows on the next merge but asynchronously 'marks' them immediately so that they are not shown in subsequent queries.

The guide i am following is here: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/delete/

But this doesn't seem to be happening as expected. After deletion it takes about 2-3 minutes before my returned queries are excluded from the results. am I missing something here?

E.g.

I have a collapsingMergeTree table called 'tests' with the following three rows:

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| syGGJVGETbzKMkayoYYaAg | kieren |
| wFhZdsdjf1xmcHGqK1CQQf | mike |
| abfZrhYkiafg7qr9jAwseG | peter |

I attempt to run

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE Id = 'syGGJVGETbzKMkayoYYaAg' SETTINGS allow_experimental_lightweight_delete=1;

// OR

SET allow_experimental_lightweight_delete=1;
DELETE FROM test WHERE Id = 'syGGJVGETbzKMkayoYYaAg'
```

However when I run the query I still get the deleted record in results, until about 5 minutes later.

I am using the clickhouse docker image (clickhouse/clickhouse-server) for my tests locally.

Thanks in advance for your help.

--- what did you try ---

Tried the documents code and expected that the results would be hidden immediately and deleted on the background as the page indicates so.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or missing something

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE FROM test` is async by default. Not only process of deletion but `DELETE` itself as well.

you can use `mutations_sync=2`:

```sql
DELETE FROM test 
WHERE Id = 'syGGJVGETbzKMkayoYYaAg' 
SETTINGS allow_experimental_lightweight_delete=1, mutations_sync=2;
```

It makes your delete synchronous.

( this behaviour was changed today BTW https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/44718 )

So currently you run `DELETE FROM test ...` it returns control immediately and does nothing!!! except it creates a mutation. This mutation asynchronously in the background changes the invisible column `_deleted` for rows matching WHERE condition, this process can take seconds, minutes, hours, days. After that your selects will not see these rows. After that eventually **OR NEVER** the marked rows will be deleted during merges, this can take months.